# Push View Controller from App Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to present and push to a view controller in another Storyboard file. But I can't get past showing the TabBar, here is the code I have and a screen shot of how I have it set up.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    let rootView = self.window!.rootViewController as! TabBarViewController
    rootView.selectedIndex = 4
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let navVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("moreNav") as! UINavigationController
    storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("moreView") as! MoreTableViewController
    let vc = navVC.visibleViewController as! MoreTableViewController


    let pdfLockerSB = UIStoryboard(name: "PDFLocker", bundle: nil)
    let pdfvc = pdfLockerSB.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("pdfLockerTable") as! PDFLockerTableViewController

    vc.navigationController?.pushViewController(pdfvc, animated: true)

    return true
}
```

[image]

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? It's a UITabBarController linked to a UINavigationController linked to a UITableViewController.

I have the segue all set up but I'm not sure why it doesn't perform it. Using Push or Perform

Comment: are you getting blank screen?

Comment: No I am not. I am getting the More screen. It just does not go on from that.

Comment: that navigationVC's index is 4, right?

Comment: Correct. There are 5 of them. It seems to switch to that just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
let navVC: UINavigationController =  rootView.viewControllers![4] as! UINavigationController;
let vc = navVC.topViewController as! MoreTableViewController
```

instead of

```
let navVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("moreNav") as! UINavigationController
let vc = navVC.visibleViewController as! MoreTableViewController
```

Comment: Yes! That worked! Can you explain what the difference really was?

Comment: you were creating new instance instead of taking reference